# Annual Community Event Proposals

Tags: discussion, community

There seems to be some interest in the idea of an annual community event, so I'm going to propose some suggestions as answers for voting.

The basic idea is a photography contest around images shot on that day and follows the standard rules of the POTW contest. The big difference in this one is that the winner gets the banner for an entire month (could be a calendar month or 4 weeks) and entered into a dedicated hall of fame.

Basic rules:

1. Image must be shot on that day.
2. Voting lasts for 2 weeks.
3. Voting and image rules match the standard Picture of the Week practice.
4. Winner is on the site banner for 1 month.

Feel free to refine this idea or let me know if I'm nuts. Please also suggest other days for this if you have a suggestion that you think might be more interesting or ***suggest an entirely different event for the community to participate in***. It could be a one-time only or a recurring event, either is fine, just something to spark the fire a little here.

Comment: I think we need to find a way to advertise this a little more. There is an advertisement feature of StackExchange that uses images posted to a thread here on meta. Those "ads" show up on all the SE sites. I think we might want to do one of those for this, see if it gets more attention. For now, this is just the idea phase...and I would like to see more ideas from more members.

Comment: @jrista - Good idea and I too would like to see more ideas. Hopefully the banner on the main site will help that. Also, if we establish an event, I think it shows up in the chat area when you select a room.

Comment: I like the idea of an event, but I don't like taking over the site banner for a month. I like to see the changing images.

Comment: @mattdm - What do you think the prize should be? It's kind of hard because it's not like we can send some swag to the winner, at least that I know of. Though if we could do something like that, it would be great.

Comment: Paging Stack Exchange employees!

Comment: Hmm...any interest since the ad went up? Or are people just voting the two answers provided so far, and not adding their own?

Comment: @jrista - The latter. There's been a little more activity, but nothing significant. I'm not giving up hope yet though. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### World Photography Day (August 19)

The connection to the site is obvious I think... The idea here is to vote on the best image taken that day, no particular theme involved.

Comment: Calling this the winner with a "massive" 12 votes... I'll start another thread to brainstorm prize ideas.

Answer (score 4):

### The UN International Day of Friendship (July 30)

This lines up nicely with the international flavour of our community. The contest would be around the image that best demonstrates the theme of *friendship*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit different than other suggestions here but this is my idea.

What if we had an event to add content to the site. Pick one of our top most voted question/answers and hold an event to add new images to it. For example this question: [What kind of photography is still better done with film cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-kind-of-photography-is-still-better-done-with-film-cameras) We could hold a contest to take infrared photos that would be added to the very highly voted up answer on the same topic.

The benefits here are that the contest could be held on any day, and it is adding content to the site which really goes along with the goals of stack exchange. It also rewards the best photo by being presented along with a very highly regarded answer. The downside that I see is if we are editing existing answers and adding photos, I'm not sure if that is advised completely. The community would have to weigh in on that part. It is my understanding since this is a community edited community wiki site, that adding an image to a great answer with no image would benefit all and be a great idea.

Comment: This is a great idea, but I see that the World Photography Day is chosen as the event. However, could it be possible to collect the questions that would benefit from visual support in a meta post that would be title something like `Answers in need of an image`? Then people could just go to that post, pick an answer, upload suitable images for it and check it off in the meta post.