# Prize for an annual event

Tags: discussion

So, the proposal for [World Photography Day](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/annual-community-event-proposals) as an event here carried the day. One of our regulars, @mattdm, suggested that a prize that took the banner for a month was a bit too much. So, what does the community see as an alternative? I think it needs to be something bigger than the standard contest, but is it a happy medium between a week or a month? Or is there something else?

Comment: One hundred *billion* dollars???

Comment: @StanRogers - Thanks for ponying that up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe reward the winner with a post on the [photo SE blog](http://photo.blogoverflow.com) featuring several photos out of the winner's portfolio + a link to a possible website?

Comment: Perhaps a two week run on the banner and a dedicated blog post would do it. That has merit, for sure.

Comment: I like this idea a lot,

Answer (score 4):

A book from Amazon.com < $30. I'm not sure how international shipping rates look, but maybe < $20 shipping as well.

An encouragement to buy a photography related book would be included but not required.

I know Stack Exchange has provided money for such things in the past, so they would need to be asked for this one to work. They call this "community's promotion funding".

Comment: Interesting idea... Not sure how to arrange that though.

Comment: We just have to ask!

Comment: It's the how to ask I'm not sure about... Maybe @jrista knows.

Comment: Probably can just @ reply anyone on the SE team like Anna or Robert